# Allow external HTTPS images on MediaWiki

Tags: configuration, https, image, mediawiki

On a MediaWiki wiki, we've set [$wgAllowExternalImages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:%24wgAllowExternalImages) which enables us to display inline images from another source without uploading it to the wiki (we just specify the URL).

However, this only works for `http` images. I'd like to display an `https` image (from our company intranet, to which the users of wiki also have access).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

mediawiki's includes/Parser.php appears to contain the code for handling this.
the version i have at hand defines EXT_IMAGE_REGEX to check image urls, and this appears to allow both http and https urls...
maybe you are using some ancient version that does not include https there?

(there is also an AllowExternalImagesFrom setting to allow images from specific domains only, but that will not override EXT_IMAGE_REGEX)

Comment: No, I was using the latest version but thanks for checking. So you think it should work as is?